# Software Publisher Certificates and Strong Name Keys are they related?

Tags: .net, authenticode, signtool

Should a Software Publisher Certificate granted by a third-part Certification Authority be used to generate a Strong Name Key for use with .NET assemblies?

Edit:

Another way of stating the question is whether code-signing and strong name keys have anything to do with each other or are they each worlds unto their own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily. Anyone can generate a key-pair and strong-name an assembly. This has advantages in preventing tampering and providing a signature. But that signature is not easy to link to a publishing party.

I'm not even sure if you can use a certificate to sign a normal assembly but it is a feature for ClickOnce apps.

Comment: I suspect that it may not be possible to use the certificate to make a strong name key.